# Why is my SQL Server query failing?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sqlconnection

```
 connect();
 $arr = mssql_fetch_assoc(mssql_query("SELECT Applications.ProductName,
        Applications.ProductVersion, Applications.ProductSize, 
        Applications.Description, Applications.ProductKey, Applications.ProductKeyID,
        Applications.AutomatedInstaller, Applications.AutomatedInstallerName,
        Applications.ISO, Applications.ISOName, Applications.Internet,
        Applications.InternetURL, Applications.DatePublished, Applications.LicenseID,
        Applications.InstallationGuide, Vendors.VendorName
FROM Applications
INNER JOIN Vendors ON Applications.VendorID = Vendors.VendorID
WHERE ApplicationID = ".$ApplicationID));

$query1 = mssql_query("SELECT Issues.AppID, Issues.KnownIssues
      FROM Issues 
      WHERE Issues.AppID=".$ApplicationID);   
$issues = mssql_fetch_assoc($query1);
$query2 = mssql_query("SELECT ApplicationInfo.AppID,
               ApplicationInfo.Support_Status, ApplicationInfo.UD_Training,
               ApplicationInfo.AtomicTraining, ApplicationInfo.VendorURL
   FROM  ApplicationInfo
   WHERE ApplicationInfo.AppID = ".$ApplicationID);
$row = mssql_fetch_assoc($query2);
function connect(){
 $connect =  mssql_connect(DBSERVER, DBO, DBPW) or 
        die("Unable to connect to server");
 $selected = mssql_select_db(DBNAME, $connect) or 
        die("Unable to connect to database");
 return $connect;
}
```

Above is the code. The first query/fetch_assoc works perfectly fine, however the next 2 queries fail and I cannot figure out why. Here is the error statement that shows up from php:

> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Invalid object name 'Issues'. (severity 16) in /srv/www/htdocs/agreement.php on line 47
>
> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server (severity 16) in /srv/www/htdocs/agreement.php on line 47
>   Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in /srv/www/htdocs/agreement.php on line 47
>
> Warning: mssql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in /srv/www/htdocs/agreement.php on line 48
>
> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: message: Invalid object name 'software.software_dbo.ApplicationInfo'. (severity 16) in /srv/www/htdocs/agreement.php on line 51
>
> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server (severity 16) in /srv/www/htdocs/agreement.php on line 51
>
> Warning: mssql_query() [function.mssql-query]: Query failed in /srv/www/htdocs/agreement.php on line 51
>
> Warning: mssql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MS SQL-result resource in /srv/www/htdocs/agreement.php on line 52

The error clearly centers around the fact that the query is not executing. In my database I have a table called Issues and a table called ApplicationInfo so I am unsure why it is telling me that they are invalid objects.

Comment: Those errors are trying to tell you that certain Tables/Fields you reference in your query are either invalid or don't exist. Double check for type-o's.

Comment: `ApplicationInfo` is different from `software.software_dbo.ApplicationInfo`

Comment: The queries *look* ok (making certain assumptions about your database structure). Do they work when you run them directly from an SSMS query window? If so, then it's not the queries themselves.

Comment: Each query works in my Squirrel SQL Client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that you're querying the right database or schema.

`software.software_dbo.ApplicationInfo` means:

- a database named `software`
- a schema named `software_dbo` - **likely this is the problem**. Likely is `dbo` on your SQL Server.
- a view/table named `ApplicationInfo`

Perhaps check what the value of `DBO`, amongst the other arguments, is in this statement: `$connect =  mssql_connect(DBSERVER, DBO, DBPW)`

Comment: Thank you. The replacement of software_dbo to dbo solved the issue. Question tho--Why does the first query not need that but the other 2 do?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see that the user you are connecting with has permission to use the tables you are trying to query. Seams like the issue is that the tables cannot be found.

The best way to handle this would be to grant the user permssions to all objects in that database:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, DELETE <any other permissions that user needs> ON `database`.`*` TO `user`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY 'password'
```

Comment: I have full permissions on each object in the database.

Comment: Just a note, the GRANT command above applies to MySQL, the original poster's question is MSSQL-related.